# Custom labels in dynamic table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, counters

I am trying to auto-generate a table, which counts its entries and gives custom labels to each entry. I am not able to get \customlabel to work properly, it always seems to reference the last entry of the list. Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

Thank you!

CLS file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myCLS}[bla]

\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

% requirements
\newcounter{NameOfTheNewCounter}
\setcounter{NameOfTheNewCounter}{0}

\newcommand\themissionreqnumber{%
\ifnum\value{NameOfTheNewCounter}<100 0\fi
\protect\arabic{NameOfTheNewCounter}}


\newcommand{\missionrequiremententries}{}
\newcommand{\missionrequirement}[3]{%
\protected@xdef\missionrequiremententries{\missionrequiremententries \protect\addtocounter{NameOfTheNewCounter}{10}MIS-\protect\themissionreqnumber & #2 & #3 \protect\\}\protect\customlabel{#1}{MIS-\protect\themissionreqnumber}}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,%
        top=3.28cm, bottom=3.10cm,%
        left=2.0cm, right=1.95cm,%
        headsep=0.2cm,headheight=50pt,heightrounded,%
        footskip=1.3cm]{geometry}%  Change the page dimensions and margins

\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}% Colours
\definecolor{lightgrey}{RGB}{230,230,230}
\RequirePackage{tabularx,booktabs,colortbl}% Improved tables
```

and main .tex file (compiling using XeLaTex)

```
\documentclass{myCLS}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
   \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{\thepage}{#2}{#1}{}} }%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\missionrequirementstable}{%
\noindent
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Requirements}\label{tab:req}
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{p{2cm}|X|p{2cm}}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgrey}{\bfseries ID} & {\bfseries Statement} & {\bfseries Parent ID}\\
    \hline
    \missionrequiremententries
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}
}



\begin{document}


\missionrequirement{myFirstLabel}{My text.}{\ref{mySecondLabel}}
\missionrequirement{mySecondLabel}{My new text.}{\ref{myFirstLabel}}

\missionrequirementstable


\ref{myFirstLabel}
\end{document}
```

yielded output:
[image]

desired output:
[image]

Comment: You need to expand `\themissionreqnumber` properly. In my point of view the test should be outside of `\themissionreqnumber`, not inside

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you mean the `\ifnum`? I thought the counting works just fine as you can see in the tables. It is counting up and as soon as the numbers are higher than MIS-100 it does not add a 0 any longer. But the `\customlabel` command apparently always gets the last counter value from when the `\ref` command is called instead of when the label is defined. Or am I missing something now?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I solved this problem. It seemed to be in the if-clause

wrong code:

```
\newcommand\themissionreqnumber{%
\ifnum\value{NameOfTheNewCounter}<100 0\fi
\protect\arabic{NameOfTheNewCounter}}
```

correction (not actually tested, but that was also the error in my first attempts of the new code, see working code below)

```
\newcommand\themissionreqnumber{%
{\ifnum\value{NameOfTheNewCounter}<100 0\fi}
\protect\arabic{NameOfTheNewCounter}}
```

But I coded it a completely different way now:

```
\newcounter{NameOfTheNewCounter}
\renewcommand{\theNameOfTheNewCounter}{MIS-{\ifnum\value{NameOfTheNewCounter}<100 0\fi}\arabic{misreqs}}
\newcommand{\NameOfTheNewCounterCnt}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{NameOfTheNewCounter}{10}% Step counter
  \theNameOfTheNewCounter% Print counter
  \addtocounter{NameOfTheNewCounter}{-1}\refstepcounter{NameOfTheNewCounter}\label{#1}}% Mark with label

\newcommand{\missionrequiremententries}{}
\newcommand{\missionrequirement}[3]{%
\protected@xdef\missionrequiremententries{\missionrequiremententries \protect\misreqCnt{#1} & #2 & #3 \protect\\}}

{\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{p{1.7cm}|p{11.9cm}|p{2cm}}
\caption{Mission Requirements}\label{tab:mission_req}\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgrey}{\bfseries Req. ID} & {\bfseries Statement} & {\bfseries Parent ID}\\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \missionrequiremententries
    \hline
\end{longtable}}}

\begin{document}


\missionrequirement{myFirstLabel}{My text.}{\ref{mySecondLabel}}
\missionrequirement{mySecondLabel}{My new text.}{\ref{myFirstLabel}}

\missionrequirementstable


\ref{myFirstLabel}
\end{document}
```